# How to dynamically load DLLs from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-services

DLLs can be easily dynamically loaded from an application, by the following steps:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

Then I call the CodeBase() method of the Assembly class to get the directory of where the app is.  Next I would call Directory.GetFiles() to get a list of all files with the DLL extension, and then call Assembly.LoadFile().

I am trying to do the same thing but for a Windows service.  When write the Windows Service Installer, I make sure all DLLs that would be dynamically loaded are also included.  The problem is I don't know the equivalent of the steps above that I use for an application.  Where is the service installed?  Which directory?

Comment: Why do you need to do this at all ? I don't understand why this is necessary.  From experience however, I seem to recall that the directory for a service seems to come out as your windows system folder.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is implemented in managed code, you can follow the pretty much the same steps as you've outlined in your question. That service is still a managed app and  `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will provide the location of your assembly, which is your service. Then you can use `GetDirectoryName` to find the service install directory.

Comment: His issue might be that the dlls is not in the same folder as the service, hence this won't work.

Comment: Totally agree. But that might open the whole new can of worms as .NET does not allow loading dlls from certain locations. However, using Assembly.LoadFrom might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/57248.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using a Installer Project template. You probably don't need to use reflection but instead look into implementing an Installer Class and during the commiting event verify that the assemblies that are required are in the target directory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx